# Hide address bar on the called VF page from custom detail page button in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I have a custom button created and i am calling a VF page to open in new window. I have also the window properites set up. I have unchecked the field 'Show Address bar " in "Window properties". But the new page still shows the address bar.

Does anyone have the same problem? Or am i doing something wrong? Below are the properties

```
Width (in pixels)   265
Height (in pixels)  300
*Window Position    No Preference
Resizeable          unchecked
Show Address Bar    unchecked
Show Scrollbars     unchecked
Show Toolbars       unchecked
Show Menu Bar       unchecked
Show Status Bar     checked
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a trend for browsers to ignore the address bar setting. I don't think there's anything you can do about it.

This [Chrome bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=81506) has some more explanation.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy... makes sense not to hide the address bar